# Ghidra can't Decompile kernelbase.dll exported functions?

Tags: disassembly, dll, ghidra

I was trying to understand the `IsDebuggerPresent()` function exported by kernelbase.dll by importing the file on Ghidra. But Ghidra can't show me the proper disassembly or decompilation of function even though disassembly works fine in PE Bear? What could be the issue? I don't know if this is the proper place to post this so please guide me to a place if it isn't. Thanks!

[image: Ghidra Disassembly/Decompilation Output]

[image: PE Bear Disassembly Output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do `ctrl + A` - select all and then press `D` to disassemble. good chance it will solve your problem.

Comment: And I'm reminded again why I love the Internet! That solved the problem, thanks so much! I'll accept your answer. Any idea why Ghidra won't do the disassembly automatically? This problem doesn't arise when I import kernel32.dll for example.

Comment: Thanks :) I have no idea, but I know that most of the disassembler has similar problems. it happens in IDA too for example.